# windows can not setup a steady connection with another local network

Tags: networking, ssh, samba

here is my office net

```
          a                         b
     |192.168.1.0/24| ————————  |192.168.6.0/24|

         |                             |
         |                             |

     |ssh server：1.2|             |windows client2：6.2|
     |samba server：1.3|           |linux client2：6.3|
     |windows client1：1.4|
     |linux client1：1.5|
```

network 192.168.1.0/24(local network a) and 192.168.6.0/24(local network b) can connect with each other,therefore the network b's client can access 192.168.1.0/24's all server.

but here is the problem:

1. Network b's windows client can establish a connect with  a's all server(samba,ssh),but it will auto disconnect in about 1-2minutes
2. Network b's linux client can establish a connect hava no problem above.
3. Network a's both windows and linux clients have no problem at item 1.
4. when l am in network b using putty to connect to network a's server,it output this error:"Software caused connection abort"

Answer (score 0):

l have solved it.

because two local network connect with a firewall,and this is usually breaking connect with some reson like limits connection because of router's memory,see this url:http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

keep alive can probe the connections which proxy or firewall does't kown the change.

so when l access samba, l add "keep alive = 10" filed in my smb.conf, and there is no connection break, and l think ssh server has some configure like samba

also, you can configure client's keep_alive , but it will affect all the offices change it.